# Output a radio button and combo box into excel spreadsheet.

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have it that when a user selects something from a combo box, and presses a button (already set up) it will output the selection into an excel spreadsheet.

The same is for a radio button selection.

I can do it for a text box, using the following code

```
Range("B8") = TextBox2.Text
```

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio button wise, you can iterate through the radio buttons, find the selected one and output the `Name` of the control like so:

```
Dim cCon as Control

For Each cCon In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cCon) = "OptionButton" And cCon.Value Then
        MsgBox cCon.Name
    End If
Next cCon
```

For a `ComboBox` you can use it's `.Value` property to return the value if there's only one column for example:

```
Range("A1").Value = ComboBox1.Value
```

If there's more than one column, you can use the following:

```
Range("A1").Value = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex,1) 'Where 1 is the column number
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth. How would I then call that as above with the text box?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You can use the above code in a worksheet module or the same module that you're running your current textbox one in.

Comment: Hi @Gareth I am getting an error. "Invalid outside procedure" ?

Comment: I can't access that site, just let me know which line the error is on.

Comment: I believe it to be on this line: For Each cCon In RadioButtonGroup.Controls

Comment: I've amended the code which should work now with all the radiobuttons on a userform.

Comment: Getting the same error on this line of code: For Each cCon In Me.Controls

Comment: Where are the radiobuttons? Are they in a userform? And where is the code running from? A separate module, worksheet module or userform module?

Comment: Hi Gareth, I have opted to just use a combo box now. Too much hassle. Thanks for your help.